# Unsure what goes in 'self.room_group_name = "..." and How it works

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I have a django project where I'm trying to connect users using websockets, I've been following tutorials to understand it, but most people's workflow is 2 pages (start at / then go to the room), mine is 3: start at login -> go to home -> go to room. I keep getting a WebSocket connection failed error and Not Found: /ws/home/room/ and have been struggling to figure out why, I'm assuming I just don't understand what's happening enough.

this is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.login, name='login'),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('home/<str:room_name>/', views.room, name='room'),
]
```

this is routing.py

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^ws/home/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.GameConsumer),
]
```

and this is my consumers.py

```
class GameConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(args, kwargs)
        self.room_name = None
        self.room_group_name = None

    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = '_%s' % self.room_name # unsure about '_%s' <--- unsure what to put here

        ''' create new group '''
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name,
        )

        await self.accept()

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'tester_message',
                'tester': 'hello world',
            }
        )

    async def tester_message(self, event):
        tester = event['tester']

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'tester': tester
        }))

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name,
        )
```

I feel like it has something to do with the room_group_name, but again struggling conceptually and haven't read a lot of sources that explain what precisely needs to go there. Any help or ideas on where to go?

this is where I create the WebSocket Object:

```
<div id="user-hello"></div>

    {{ room_name|json_script:"room-name" }}
    <script>
        const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('room-name').textContent)
        const socket = new WebSocket(
            'ws://' +
            window.location.host +
            '/ws/home/' +
            roomName +
            '/'
        );

        socket.onmessage = function (e) {
            const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            console.log(data);
            document.querySelector('#user-hello').innerHTML = (data.tester)
        }
    </script>
```

This was originally for a bigger project, decided it would be easier to cut out all the junk and solely focus on the websocket issue. So besides messing around in the bigger project I haven't tried much for this

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I didn't know I had to dock my project and it was different from tutorials because I am on a windows machine. so if your on a windows machine Here are the steps I took

1. Install and set up Memurai
   https://www.memurai.com/get-memurai#
2. Install and set up Docker Desktop
   https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/

- Add C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin
  & C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources to path environment variables

3. In Django Terminal, make sure channels, daphne, and redis are installed
   channels: python -m pip install -U channels
   daphne: python -m pip install daphne
   redis: python -m pip install channels_redis

   - If some are already installed check to make sure

-> restart computer here

4. Make sure memurai is running in windows services

- Windows search bar -> open 'services' -> scroll to memurai and ensure its running

5. Make sure Docker Desktop is running
6. Start redis server port on 6379
   docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis:5

--> also need to edit CHANNEL_LAYERS in settings.py to: "hosts": ["redis://localhost:6379"],